# the poster child for Covid-19 handling

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is "poster child" an approving term in the following? Does it mean more or less the same as "role model" here?

> ‘How quarantine keeps families apart’. New Zealand is the **poster child** for Covid-19 handling, right? Prime Minister Jacinda Ardern preaches “be kind”. But in case you missed it, here’s a reminder that quarantine bureaucracy is cruel when you’re trying to visit a loved-one half a world away. (Business Desk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary defintion "a person or thing that epitomizes or represents a specified quality, cause, etc" applies.  It tends to carry a positive nuance. Literally a "poster child" is the child chosen to appear on a poster advertising something. So a school would choose its neatest, happiest, most attractive child to put on the poster.

So if New Zealand is the poster child for Covid 19 handling, it means that New Zealand epitomizes the very best. It seems likely that the rest of the article will suggest that New Zealand is not as wonderful as some believe.